# Is there a better way to handle double click in pygobject

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, pygobject

I've been using the following for handling double click:

```
    def do_button_press_event(self, eb: Gdk.EventButton):
    if eb.type == Gdk.EventType._2BUTTON_PRESS:
        # todo: code double click
        pass
```

Accessing the *private* property `_2BUTTON_PRESS` feels a bit dirty. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a private property: it's an artefact of the C enumeration member being `GDK_2BUTTON_PRESS`. Python does not allow identifiers to start with a number, so when translating the symbol `GDK_2BUTTON_PRESS` in the `GdkEventType` C enumeration into a field in `Gdk.EventType` Python class, PyGOBject needs to escape the `2BUTTON_PRESS` part.

To avoid this, GTK introduced a `GDK_DOUBLE_BUTTON_PRESS`, which is correctly translated as `Gdk.EventType.DOUBLE_BUTTON_PRESS`.

The same explanation also applies to the `GDK_3BUTTON_PRESS`/`GDK_TRIPLE_BUTTON_PRESS` enumeration fields.

Comment: If Im right, double clicks are avoided as per HIG right?

Comment: I assume by "HIG" you mean "the GNOME human interface guidelines", in which case: not really, no. It's better to have single clicks to ensure functionality with touch screens, but it's entirely possible to use double clicks.